# asp.net concurrency / conflict detection problem

Tags: asp.net, concurrency

I have a page where users can assign tasks to persons. They select a task and one or more persons or a group of persons. This is done by cascading listviews. The first listview contains the group, drilling down the individual persons for the selected group when needed.

When the user selects a task and a group of persons, in my database the persons in those groups are assigned the task, not the group itself. Making it flexible so one or more persons from different groups can be assigned the same task.

So the user won't actually see the indivual persons when they select a group and i dont have to load them. Only when they drill down i load the persons for that group.

As i mentioned when assigning to a group i update the persons in that group but since i didn't load them i don't know what their old task was.

That makes me think when loading the groups i should store for each person his old task so later i can compare them.

**Question 1:**
What would be a good way to store the old person's task so i can compare it to the new task? If they differ i have a conflict and can abort the update telling the user to refresh his page.

(Note that in the real program i have nested groups which can contain thousands of people in the top level group to several in the lowest level group).

**Question 2:**
As for general conflict detection could it be a good idea to compare the timestamp (if any) when the page was first loaded to the timestamp (i have) a record was updated? If the record was updated after the page was loaded i can inform the user? I wouldn't know though if it was data he's working on that changed because different pages can update different fields in the same record, not creating any conflict in that case but changing the timestamp however.